# Is $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ a Kähler manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ be the special linear group of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices with determinant $1$. We know it's a complex lie group. In particular, it's a (non-compact) complex 3-fold.

**My question is:**
Can it be endowed with the structure of a Kähler manifold?

Comment: It is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb C^4$, so it inherits the standard Kähler metric.

Comment: @IEm You mean the standard Hermitian metric?

Answer (score 2):

A manifold $X$ of dimension $2n$ admits an almost Kähler structure if its principal $GL(2n, \mathbb{R})$-bundle, given by frames in $TM$, can be reduced to $SO(n,\mathbb{R}) \cap GL(n,\mathbb{C}) \cap Sp(n,\mathbb{R})$ (This amounts to find compatible Riemannian, almost-complex and simplectic structures), since $M=G$ is a lie group, $TG = G \times \mathfrak{g}$ its principal bundle is trivial and the reduction just amounts to the inclusion of groups and those are subgroups, we get that there is always an almost käler structure. If we start with an integrable almost-complex structure, then we have a proper Kähler structure.

In plain english: fix any scalar product $g$ in the Lie algebra of $G$ that is compatible with the almost complex structure $J$ ($J$ is an isometry) given by the multiplication by $i$ in $T_eG = \mathfrak g$ and then move it around $G$ via left-translations to get Riemannian metric. Finally, define the symplectic structure by $\omega(x,y) = g(x,Jy)$, we get a kähler structure.

Comment: Is this really necessary? As mentioned in the comment by @IEm, $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^4$ which is Kähler, and hence is Kähler.

Comment: I am not sure if being inside $C^n$ means much as any manifold is inside some $C^n$ . maybe it only works for $n=4$  and I rather stay away from those kind of arguments.

Comment: $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^4$ because of the "determinant $=1$" condition. We also know any submanifold of a Kähler manifold is Kähler.

Comment: You need to add more details to that as the circle is clearly a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}$ and is not even a complex manifold. On the other hand the zero locus of any polynomial $p(z)$ is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$ but that isnt enough to be kahler for $n$ greater than 2.

Comment: By a submanifold, I meant a complex submanifold.

Comment: What's an example of the zero locus of a polynomial but not Kähler?